# how to render custom layout of the projection of known content items

Tags: orchardcms, projection

I have defined my own projection by a query which returns a set of content items of known content type. I would like to take pick up certain content parts of these content items and display them in the list. Using shape tracing tool I have found the view template where to write my custom layout:
*/Views/Parts.ProjectionPart.cshtml*

but from the Model variable in the template I can not get the data I want because it is way too high above from the content parts data.

a good example of what I want: let's say I want to render product catalog as defined in this tutorial:
http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-5

but I want only to render a list which consists from items:

1. name of the owner who created the product
2. name of the product.
3. publish date of the product

and I need to render it at one place, i.e., not separately in their own part views.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a layout in the projector module?  There is a properties mode option that lets you select which fields/data to show.  If the data you want is not there, you should be able to implement an IPropertyProvider.  There are examples of this in the Projections module code.